# Python SQL Error: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.1:3306' (10061) SSMS

Tags: python, sql, ssms

it seems I can't connect to my SQL Server Management Studios (installed on a Win machine) database and I don't know why since some other scheduled Python jobs I personally created that execute other queries work just fine.

This is an example of my code:

```
import sys
import mysql.connector

try:

  conn = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="192.168.1.1",
      user="sa",
      password="sa",
      database="Test"
  ) 
  cursor = conn.cursor()

  query = "SELECT * FROM [DB] WHERE [Art] = 'EX'"
  cursor.execute(query)
  row = cursor.fetchall()

  if cursor.rowcount == 0:
     print("No results")
     sys.exit()


except Exception as e:

  print(e)
```

Everytime throws the error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.1:3306' (10061)

And yes, I checked if any services were down (like written on other answers I found on the internet) but they all were up

I tried to execute my script on 2 other PCs but it didn't work

I even tried restarting the server and guess what, it didn't work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you are trying to connect with *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio* using Python.

If so, you need **pyodbc** python module.

To install pyodbc module, open cmd and run the following:

```
python -m pip install pyodbc
```

Now, to connect database :

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                    'Server=username\SQLEXPRESS;'
                    'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

Replace 'username' with your desktop username

find pyodbc documentation [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki)

also you can follow [this](https://datatofish.com/how-to-connect-python-to-sql-server-using-pyodbc/)

Comment: I tried this and it worked, thanks. What I don't get it is why my other scripts not using pyodbc are working perfectly fine.

Comment: are you using _Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio_ for other scripts? Or anything else like xampp(apache/mysql server)?

Comment: All my other scripts execute one or more queries only to SSMS, I don't have any xampp running